# OPC UA server not sending events when OPC UA client is running inside Docker

Tags: .net, docker, opc-ua, opc

Facing a very weird and interesting problem. Let me try to explain the situation in the following section.

We are using OPC UA Server that can send both Numeric and Events. Also, we have one OPC UA Client Application (our own .NET application) which is able to subscribe to both Numeric and Events. Our application is also able to subscribe to multiple OPC UA Servers simultaneously. Now, let's consider the following scenarios,

Scenario A: OPC UA Client Application is running on Windows. It is able to subscribe, receive and store both Numeric and Events without and issue.

Scenario B: We have made docker image of the same OPC UA Client Application. Now, when we create and execute this docker container, our application is able to connect to the same OPC UA Server. It's successfully subscribing and receiving to Numeric data. It is also successfully subscribing to Events. But not receiving any Events data. It is, as if, when we are connecting OPC UA Client from docker container, OPC UA Server is not sending any Events at all.

Need help in understanding what's wrong in this scenario. And what should be our approach to debug this issue.

Comment: I would use Wireshark to determine whether the server is actually sending the events (and the client not "seeing" them - then just focus on the client), or not sending them at all. If the server is not sending the events - you can analyze whether it is because the client did something wrong, or the client is OK and the server is at fault, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to understand which data packet contains numeric and which one contains events using Wireshark? I'm unable to understand that.

Comment: The NotificationMessage in the PublishResponse contains notificationData array. Elements of this array are either DataChangeNotification, or EventNotificationList (or StatusChangeNotification) - this is the distinction you have asked about.